# How to write test in angularjs according to john papa style guide

Tags: angularjs, testing, controller

I am new to writing test in angularjs.I have a controller which i have written according to john papa style guide.I need to access those methods in the controller in my test case.How do i do it?I am using jasmine.My sample code is:

```
(function(){
  angular.module('myapp')
  .controller('AlertsController', AlertsController);
AlertsController.$inject = ['$scope', 'StorageFactory']
function AlertsController($scope, StorageFactory) {
  var vm=this;
  vm.createAlert=createAlert();
  function createAlert(){
    //function code
    }  
})
```

and my test is as follows:

```
 'use strict';
 describe('Controller: AlertsController', function() {
var AlertsController, scope, StorageFactory;

beforeEach(module('myapp'));
beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _StorageFactory_,      _$rootScope_) {
    scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    AlertsController = _$controller_;
    StorageFactory = _StorageFactory_;
}));

var createController = function() {
    AlertsController('AlertsController', {
        '$scope': scope,
        'StorageFactory': StorageFactory
    });

};
 it('should create an alert', function() {
    spyOn(StorageFactory, 'isLoggedIn').and.callFake(function() {
        return true;
    });
    createController();
    expect(AlertsController).toBeDefined();
    AlertsController.createAlert();  
});
});
```

Am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'AlertsController.createAlert()') in /Users/Ramya/Documents/panitr_mobile/test/spec/controllers/AlertsCtrlSpec.js (line 57)
    at /Users/Ramya/Documents/panitr_mobile/test/spec/controllers/AlertsCtrlSpec.js:57:37
PhantomJS 2.0.0 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.242 secPhantomJS 2.0.0 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.054 secs / 0.242 secs)
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Jhon Papa` style, you don't need to create `scope` using `$new`.
simply pass `{}` while creating controller instead of `$scope`.

And place controller initialization inside `beforeEach`;

```
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _StorageFactory_,      _$rootScope_) {
            AlertsController = _$controller_;
            StorageFactory = _StorageFactory_;
            AlertsController('AlertsController', {} });
        }));

it("creatAlert should be defined",function(){

     expect(AlertsController.creatAlert ).toBe(true);
})
```

Comment: i need to access createAlert method in the test,can you tell me how?

Comment: i tried your updated answer but am getting the error "Expected undefined to be true."

Comment: console the `AlertsController` in the `inject` block,check it what it is outputting?

Comment: I tried printing the AlertsController but its not printing the method inside it.What am i doing wrong?

Comment: thanks for your reply.But i found the answer in the following link : https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/unit-testing-angularjs-applications